# writing context free grammar in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, context-free-grammar, dcg

let's say I had the following context free grammar.

```
S -> A
A -> mAn
A -> o
```

How would this look in prolog? This is what I tried but it doesn't work. The second line seems to be the issue.

```
S(Z) :- A(Z).
A(Z) :- append([m],X,Z2), A(X), append(Z2,[n],Z).
A([o]).
```

Comment: Dont write `A(Z)`, but `a(Z)`. Similarly with all predicate names...

Answer (score 4):

since the grammar is not left recursive, we can use a [DCG](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dcg/info):

```
s --> a.
a --> [m], a, [n].
a --> [o].
```

then we can parse or generate all accepted sequences. For instance, generating:

```
?- length(L, _), phrase(s, L).
L = [o] 
L = [m, o, n] 
L = [m, m, o, n, n] 
...
```

to inspect the Prolog code:

```
?- listing(s).
s(A, B) :-
    a(A, B).

?- listing(a).
a([m|A], C) :-
    a(A, B),
    B=[n|C].
a([o|A], A).
```

no append/3 required, thanks to difference lists

*edit* using append/3

```
s(Z) :- a(Z).
a(Z) :- append([m|X],[n],Z), a(X).
a([o]).
```

SWI-Prolog has append/2 (simply based on append/3 properly chained), that give
a more readable alternative

```
a(Z) :- append([[m],X,[n]], Z), a(X).
```

anyway, we must call a/1 recursively *after* the list has been built/split

Comment: Cool. How would it be like if append/3 were used?

Comment: Why do you put `a([o]).` last?

Comment: @false: I was attempting to keep the code most similar to the original

Answer (score 3):

In this answer, we use the commonly available predicate [`append/3`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#append).

```
s(Xs) :-
   a(Xs).

a([o]).
a([m|Xs]) :-
   append(Xs0,[n],Xs),
   a(Xs0).
```

Sample query:

```
?- length(Xs,_), s(Xs).
   Xs = [o]
;  Xs = [m,o,n]
;  Xs = [m,m,o,n,n]
;  Xs = [m,m,m,o,n,n,n] 
...
```

**NOTE:** Using `append/3` instead of [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) is, in general, a bad choice and can contribute to both lower runtime performance and code readability.  Whenever possible, use [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg) instead!